# Structural notation for multi-element FCC crystal structures

Tags: condensed-matter, solid-state-physics, material-science, crystals, metals

I was wondering if different compound FCC structures share any kind of indicator or structural notation which I could use to find and categorise them.

To clarify my problem: the FCC **L12** structure, found in Cu3Au, has a SC Bravais Lattice, space number of 221 and pearson symbol of cP4. Despite having the same elemental ratios as **L12**, the FCC **DO22** structure, found in TiAl3, has a BCC bravais lattice, space number 139 and pearson symbol of tI8.

I understand that these descriptors are useful in defining the repeating grids of unique points, but if I wanted to only search FCC superstructures in a database such as materials project, is it possible to specify such a query?

Thanks for your help,

Philip

Comment: So, to be clear, you want to be able to extract any structure that has atom positions, and ignoring atom type, that looks like a close packed structure with A-B-C stacking regardless of the underlying Bravais lattice type? (To my way of thinking, an "FCC superstructure" has to have FCC symmetries, so if the Bravais lattice is SC or BCC they don't apply - hence my question).

Comment: Yes that's exactly my question! Perhaps the stacking order is indeed a better way of looking at the problem.

Comment: In general that is going to be hard. You might want to play with what info in your database(s) is available to use, then compare known L1$_{0}$, L1$_{2}$, and DO$_{23}$ phases to see if the data have characteristics that can be used to identify these known fcc-like phases. As a further test, something like Mn-Pd would be good, particularly how to distinguish the two L1$_{0}$ and the B2 phases around 50:50 mixes that exist at different temperatures.

Comment: And it sounds like any face-centered tetragonal phase might be a possibility as well. And you want to exclude anything that is not strictly A-B-C (no hcp A-B, or dhcp A-B-A-C or odder options)?

Comment: At the moment I am looking for a way to exclusively search simple ABC materials, however if a method is found which includes exotic face-centered structures I wouldn't mind. Many thanks for your suggestions!